# Responsive image map not working. Need another solution

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagemap

can anyone help me out of an issue please?
Check out the attached image.
Layer 1 is a background image.
Layer 2 is a logo.png
Layer 3 needs to be 2 buttons, exactly at the position shown.
The shown logo is made with Photoshop, but the buttons need to be seperate and always at the correct position. They can be made of png or even html/css buttons.

I tried to make a responsive image map with Javascript but it does not work properly on my webpage.

Maybe someone has an idea how to solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Please add more information regarding what you have already tried so people can know what exact issue you're running into. Otherwise, this question is too broad. Maybe you can post the code that you wrote to try making a responsive image map?

Comment: Image maps determine click targets by using pixel coordinates; resizing the image responsively doesn't change those coordinates automatically. You'll need a JavaScript solution; [here's one I found in a quick search](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer).

Comment: I know this thing with the resizing issue and JavaScript. There are some online responsive image map generators which gives you the code and a JS file.

I tried this one for example:

http://image-map.weebly.com/